# Deleting Data in Many-to-Many relationship or status = inactive

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I am planing on having a few many-to-many table relations. What is the best way to "delete" from the tables? Should I mark a column as deleted?

**Talbes**

```
CREATE TABLE `comments`(
id INT NOT NULL,
comment TEXT,
status enum('active','inactive','deleted'), //Should this be added?
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `files`(
id INT NOT NULL
file_path VARCHAR(100),
status enum('active','inactive','deleted'), //Should this be added?
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE `comments_files_xref`(
comment_id INT NOT NULL,
file_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (comment_id,file_id)
);
```

Should I set the status column to inactive and put a WHERE table.status = 'active' in my select statements? Should I just delete the rows? Which is best for performance? I could always run a cron to "clean" status = "deleted" rows.

Comment: That's actually quite a complicated issue. Since the results would be different, which MySQL engine are you using? MyISAM, InnoDB, ...?

Comment: Which should I use? I like the idea of InnoDB because of the foreign key constraints however I cannot find any good resources that describe how to tune InnoDB. MyISAM just seems so much easier or maybe I'm just that much of a noob

Comment: Thanks for the revision !  Added a para.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on several things.  Your question is not entirely clear.   Based on your comments, where you have located the IsDeleted indicator, I will assume that if either Comment or File is deleted, then you want to delete CommentFile as well,  Sounds weird but I will go with it.

1. If the number of rows in CommentFile is small, for each single row in Comment or File, then just delete them.
2. If it is large, then sure, it is a consideration, and IsDeleted is a good idea.  Then yes, you need a cron job that runs in the background, at lower priority and deletes WHERE IsDeleted = 1, in batches of 1,000.
3. But changing every Select to include WHERE IsDeleted = 0, is not going to work.  It will table scan.  To overcome that (make Select in (2) work as planned), you need to add an index, which slows inserts and deletes even more.  So I would forget (3) altogether and go with (2) only; if you have many Deletes, run two cron jobs, one ascending and one descending.
4. Better yet, have the purge jobs running in an endless loop, started once per day by cron.  You can run more than two concurrently: divide the table by PK range into no_of_jobs.  Monitor the jobs, and true online tasks, tweak by inserting a tiny delay (eg 1 or 5 secs) into the loop.  This is what we do in large OLTP banking systems.

Answer (score 0):

First, design your database so that it matches the needs of your application.  If you require easy "undelete" or "view deleted records" functionality, go with an IsDeleted column and perform logical rather than physical deletes.  If you do not need that functionality don't complicate your life by worrying about stripping out the logically deleted records from every query.

Then, if you determine that you have some kind of performance problem around the issue of deletes, you can optimize at that time.  Unless you do a lot of deleting or have truly enormous data sets it's fairly unlikely you'll run into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just unload the rows you plan to delete into archive tables in the same db or another warehouse db then physically delete the rows from your production db?